# W3C validator: “Element head is missing a required instance of child element title”

Tags: w3c-validation

For http://www.filmiclub.com/, I am getting this error in the W3C validator:

> Element `head` is missing a required instance of child element `title`

But when I copy the HTML and do validation with "Validate by direct input", the HTML is 100% error free and there is no validation error.

Do you know why PHP generated HTML with this error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue when I enter the URI in the "Validate by URI" box.

Comment: I checked by Validate by URI. I get following error. I see  23 Errors, 69 warning(s). The root element is div instead of html. Mine is html5 code. but validator is detecting as HTML 4.01 Transitional. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the "Show source" option and click Revalidate, you'll see the cause. your PHP script is crashing when receiving a request from the validator, so then PHP sends out its own error message response instead of your website.

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message: Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/common_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 7328</p>
```

Apparently the W3C's validator sends a HTTP request that **does not** have the `Accept:` header, but your PHP code expects the HTTP_ACCEPT header to be present and fails because it is absent.

Change your PHP code to detect the presence (or lack of) `Accept` header, like so:

```
if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] ) ) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dai. I have been investigating this issue last 2 days. My page is 100% valid now.. Thanks a lot !!!!